# Is a human corpse still refered as he/she?

Tags: pronouns

Lately one of thoughts turned morbid: would a person refer to a corpse as an object (it), or do corpses follow the general he/she/it rules of
Animals vs. People? My thoughts stem from the fact that a corpse was a person, but technically is not a person anymore since he/she is dead.

Ex. The corpse was... . The monster played with it [the corpse].

Ex. The corpse... . The woman took him [the corpse] to the river.

Additionally, is either one more acceptable, or simply used to convey more human sentiment to a reader?

Comment: Both are grammatically possible (it vs.  he or she) but the meaning will change. When using *he* or *she*, the former personhood (or at least the gender) of the deceased is invoked; when using *it*, it's an object.  It is customary for medical schools  to have ceremonies where those who have donated their bodies to science are thanked, BTW. But it's also customary for mobsters to say of a dead body that they "dumped it in the river".

Comment: .... or that "he's swimming with the fishes".  So you can pick the meaning and level of respect or disrespect that you intend.

Comment: @TimRomano I think that's the answer. Maybe turn it into one?

Comment: @TimRomano: It's "sleeping with the fishes". Corpses don't swim. At best they float.

Comment: Depends who's referring to it/him/her, and in what context. Should be closed as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer depends on the context and the speaker.

If one is speaking about a *body* or a *corpse*, "it" is often used. Partly, it is for psychological reasons. We often don't want to identify with the dead person. If you are writing for a rag, then you'll write:

*He* was found half-eaten in a ravine frequented by coyotes.

If you're writing more thoughtfully, you might write:

*It/the remains* was/were found by some hikers in a wilderness area.

Anyone who cares about the person will usually refer to the "body's" gender:

> "I don't want his mother to see him this way. Look how they massacred my boy!" - Don Corleone

In medical school, we referred to "our" cadavers as he/she.

Comment: By the way, what is a rag?

Comment: @KiroYakuza - A rag is a newspaper that caters to the baser instincts with sensational and often bad writing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A corpse is referred to as "it";  a dead person is referred to as "he" or "she".  The emphasis is either on the empty husk or on what once filled it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gender is still specified.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for some guidance on how to write good answers that meet StackExchange standards. Without citations or examples, no one can evaluate this submission as anything more than your personal opinion, even if it happens to be accurate.